# create-react-app build breaks some images

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, yarnpkg

OK, this one has me way confused. All images work just fine when running `yarn start` in development, but certain images break in production after running `yarn build`. All images are imported and used in the same way:

```
import pdf from "../images/pdf.png";
import ppt from "../images/ppt.png";
import xls from "../images/xls.png";
import mov from "../images/mov.png";
import dir from "../images/dir.png";
import doc from "../images/doc.png";
import indd from "../images/indd.png";
```

And sample from the code:

```
{file_type === "DOC" && (
  <img src={doc} style={styles.icon} alt="file icon" />
)}
{file_type === "Presentation" && (
  <img src={ppt} style={styles.icon} alt="file icon" />
)}
```

Again, this works just fine in development. But in production, the `doc` image works, and the `ppt` image does not, it just shows up as cannot be found.

In the build dir, `/build/static/media/` the icons that don't work show up here, for example as `doc.7397528b.png` but there is no `ppt` icon in sight.

Any ideas?!

Edit:
Here is a snippet of the code once compiled and running in prod. The first image doesn't show, the second one does.

[image]